# What type of burner ring and gas line do I need for NG fire pit?

Tags: pipe, fireplace, natural-gas, fire-pit, gas-burner

I'm planning an instal for a natural gas fire pit in my back yard, and trying to determine what I should be looking at for parts and sizing, as well as what i can expect as the final result.  Just so you know, the actual installation will be performed by a professional.  I don't want to blow myself up.

my house currently has a 250 CF meter and about 65' of 1.25" pipe  with 195,000 BTU worth of appliances at the end (stove, furnace, water heater).

I'm planning to use 3/4" for the line to the fire pit

There are three possible routes for the gas line to the fire pit:

1. about 25 feet off the end of the 1.25" pipe (has to exit the house, short trench)
2. about 75 feet off a tee on the meter (more difficult to trench, fully outside)
3. about 105 feet off a the meter (easier to trench, also outside)

Fire pit burner rings in the size I want (24-30 inches) are rated for "max BTU" from about 290,000 to 400,000.  Obviously I'm not going to be able to supply that with a 3/4" pipe of basically any length.

So my questions are:

**What could I supply with those options, and would it be enough for a decent display?**

**with a 250 CF meter, am I at risk of running out of supply and hurting or not being able to use the other appliances on the meter?**

**How would I actually calculate the BTU of the fire ring for the building permit if the supply is lower than rated max?**